# How can i use/change 2 "res.render" in different files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, controller

I don't know if the "res.render" can used twice. The error is:

```py
C:\ReactVap\vapinto\src\controller\LaunchController.js:45
    return res.render('index', { launch })
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
```

Router i have this:

```
routes.get('/index', (req, res) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      // console.log(req.user)
      res.render('index', LaunchController.index, {user:req.user});
    } else {
      res.render('login', {
        title: 'Home',
        user: req.user,
        message: res.locals.message,
      });
    }
  }
)
```

in the controller i have this:

```
async index(req,res) {
    const lancamentos = await Launch.get()

    let saldoAnterior = 0;

    let launch = lancamentos.map((item) => {     
       // Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}).format(money)
      // .toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'})
      // .toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')

      const dataFormatada = LaunchUtils.dataFormatada(item)
      const receita = LaunchUtils.receita(item)
      const despesa = LaunchUtils.despesa(item)

      const saldoAtual = receita - despesa
      const saldo = saldoAnterior + saldoAtual;
      saldoAnterior = saldo;  

      return{        
        ...item,
        dataFormatada,
        receita, 
        despesa,
        saldo        
      }      
    })

    const month = '';
    if(month > 0) {
      launch = launch.filter(item => {    
        const month = req.query.month;
        const data = new Date(item.data);
        const dataString = (data.getFullYear() + "-" + ((data.getMonth() + 1)) + "-" + (data.getDate() ))
        
        return LaunchUtils.formatDate(dataString).getMonth() == month 
      })
    } 
    return res.render('index', { launch })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the render done in a common file

**Example:**

```
module.exports = {

  renderApp(res, config){
    const defaults = {
        let a = 10,
        ...config
     };

     return res.render('index', defaults) // index path should've been set (app.set(....))
  }

}
```

Wherever you want to use render, import this and use it with the applicable configs

Comment: But where should i call these codes? in routes or controllers? My idea is, after confirm user, the view "index" will be render with the controller configuration.

Comment: From your code above, my understanding is you want to render the index with some config when the '/index' route is hit and the same to be rendered with the launch config data in the controller? You could do something like app.use('/', routes) which will take you to routes.js where you could do the render with respective config for different scenarios.